# Transition from imp to importlib

Tags: python, python-3.x

A project that I would like to use has parts of code

```
_VALID_MODULE_TYPES = set((imp.PY_SOURCE, imp.PY_COMPILED, imp.C_EXTENSION))
```

[...]

```
for suffix, mode, type in imp.get_suffixes():
        if type in self._VALID_MODULE_TYPES:
           path = prefix + suffix
           if self.file_system.isfile(path):
                   return path, type
```

[...]

```
if type == imp.PY_SOURCE:
        code = self.file_system.readbytes(path).replace(b("\r\n"), b("\n"))
        return compile(code, path, "exec")
elif type == imp.PY_COMPILED:
        code = self.file_system.readbytes(path)
        if code[:4] != imp.get_magic():
                return None
        return marshal.loads(code[8:])
elif type == imp.C_EXTENSION:
        code = self.file_system.readbytes(path)
```

which use the module `imp`. It is said that `imp` is deprecated and that `importlib` should be used instead, but I do not know how to transition. How do I have to rewrite the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## 1) Inspection

1. We realize that `imp.get_magic()` can be replaced by `importlib.util.MAGIC_NUMBER`.
2. Then we inspect `imp.get_suffixes`

```
def get_suffixes():
    """**DEPRECATED**"""
    extensions = [(s, 'rb', C_EXTENSION) for s in machinery.EXTENSION_SUFFIXES]
    source = [(s, 'r', PY_SOURCE) for s in machinery.SOURCE_SUFFIXES]
    bytecode = [(s, 'rb', PY_COMPILED) for s in machinery.BYTECODE_SUFFIXES]

    return extensions + source + bytecode
```

and we notice that

- `get_suffixes` uses some "magic numbers" `imp.PY_SOURCE`, `imp.PY_COMPILED`, `imp.C_EXTENSION`
- `get_suffixes` uses `machinery` from `importlib`

## 2) Refactoring to get independent of `imp`

We rewrite the code from before. We improve further on it by

- using `Enum`
- using `is` instead of `==` in the last chunk

```
import importlib.machinery

class ModuleType(Enum):
    SEARCH_ERROR = 0
    PY_SOURCE = 1
    PY_COMPILED = 2
    C_EXTENSION = 3
    PY_RESOURCE = 4
    PKG_DIRECTORY = 5
    C_BUILTIN = 6
    PY_FROZEN = 7
    PY_CODERESOURCE = 8
    IMP_HOOK = 9

# _VALID_MODULE_TYPES = {ModuleType.PY_SOURCE, ModuleType.PY_COMPILED}
_VALID_MODULE_TYPES = {ModuleType.PY_SOURCE, ModuleType.PY_COMPILED, ModuleType.C_EXTENSION}


def get_suffixes():
    extensions = [(s, 'rb', C_EXTENSION) for s in importlib.machinery.EXTENSION_SUFFIXES]
    source = [(s, 'r', PY_SOURCE) for s in importlib.machinery.SOURCE_SUFFIXES]
    bytecode = [(s, 'rb', PY_COMPILED) for s in importlib.machinery.BYTECODE_SUFFIXES]

    return extensions + source + bytecode
```

[...]

```
for suffix, mode, type in get_suffixes():
        if type in _VALID_MODULE_TYPES:
           path = prefix + suffix
           if self.file_system.isfile(path):
                   return path, type
```

[...]

```
if type is PY_SOURCE:
        code = self.file_system.readbytes(path).replace(b("\r\n"), b("\n"))
        return compile(code, path, "exec")
elif type is PY_COMPILED:
        code = self.file_system.readbytes(path)
        if code[:4] != importlib.util.MAGIC_NUMBER:
                return None
        return marshal.loads(code[8:])
elif type is C_EXTENSION:
        code = self.file_system.readbytes(path)
```

## 3) Further refactoring

We can also further refactor by writing

```
_VALID_MODULE_TYPES = [ModuleType.PY_SOURCE, ModuleType.PY_COMPILED, ModuleType.C_EXTENSION]

def get_suffixes(return_as_dict=False):
    if return_as_dict:
        suffixes = {
            ModuleType.C_EXTENSION: (importlib.machinery.EXTENSION_SUFFIXES, 'rb'),
            ModuleType.PY_SOURCE: (importlib.machinery.SOURCE_SUFFIXES, 'r'),
            ModuleType.PY_COMPILED: (importlib.machinery.BYTECODE_SUFFIXES, 'rb')
        }
    else:
        extensions = [(s, 'rb', ModuleType.C_EXTENSION) for s in importlib.machinery.EXTENSION_SUFFIXES]
        source = [(s, 'r', ModuleType.PY_SOURCE) for s in importlib.machinery.SOURCE_SUFFIXES]
        bytecode = [(s, 'rb', ModuleType.PY_COMPILED) for s in importlib.machinery.BYTECODE_SUFFIXES]
        suffixes = extensions + source + bytecode
    return suffixes
```

so that we can set in which order we want to go through the `_VALID_MODULE_TYPES` and we also improve by iterating less when

```
suffixes = get_suffixes(return_as_dict=True)
for module_type in _VALID_MODULE_TYPES:
    for suffix in suffixes[module_type][0]:
        path = prefix + suffix
        if self.file_system.isfile(path):
            return path, module_type
return None, None
```

Comment: It's really not clear where the enum values in `ModuleType` come from. How do you know that `PY_SOURCE` is 1?

Comment: @MikeC: I do not remember (it is a while ago). I think, I got it from some kind of documentation.